# Adjective for questions that demonstrate good understanding

Tags: single-word-requests

How can questions that demonstrate great understanding of a topic (rather than ignorance) be described?

As in, the question is extremely deep, or the question raises some fundamental implications, etc., and it is likely that even experts would need to do some good thinking to answer the question.

> He asked several _____ questions

I would like something a bit more specific than generic synonyms-of-intelligent words like

- intelligent
- knowledgeable
- astute

etc. because I really want to capture the perhaps-subtle meaning that the question *demonstrates* that the speaker themselves is well-read about the topic, rather than that the speaker/question *is* smart. Although of course, if any words like these are commonly/idiomatically applied in this specific scenario, then they'd be great answers too.

Comment: First thought - _probing questions_ but maybe does not fit well in this scenario

Comment: Why doesn't [_knowledgeable_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knowledgeable) demonstrate that the person asking the question is well-read?

Comment: "excogitative , nontrivial"

Comment: "relevant", "pertinent", "a propos"?

Comment: *Knowledgeable* is best of all the examples on the page at showing someone is well-read or well-informed on a topic (rather than generally intelligent, or being a question that shows perceptiveness or is hard to answer). But it appears the OP prefers other words, so maybe the question needs to be edited to communicate what the OP actually wants, rather than what the OP says they want (this is a very common occurrence).

Comment: Maybe "Socratic" -- meaning that it is clear they're attempting to guide the discussion to interesting areas by asking questions.

Answer (score 44):

Insightful

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/insightful)

> having or showing an accurate and deep understanding; perceptive:

Comment: The MW definition for this doesn't really fill out the related nuance as to why this is the better answer, compared to simply "perceptive" alone. Further, not only is it the better word for this scenario semantically, it's also idiomatically the word that is used generally for the related phrasing.

Answer (score 14):

Try *perceptive*:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perceptive)
> Perceptive:
> very good at noticing and understanding things that many people do not notice

Hence a perceptive question is one based on an understanding of the things most likely to be the basis of an answer, or raises issues only seen by someone with deep understanding of the difficulties of answering it.

Comment: I love this answer, no idea why it's downvoted. Seems to be just the kind of word that I'm after and I'm sure that I've seen it in this context before. I won't accept it just yet because it didn't ring any bells for me the same way the "that's the one!" word often does when I ask here.

Comment: Since it got downvoted but I love it so much, does someone find that my question doesn't properly convey what I intend to ask? Could I improve my question?

Comment: Not my DV but, *perceptive* could also apply to someone who knows nothing about the subject up front, but is smart enough to quickly perceive the intricacies in the subject and ask questions to flesh-out their understanding.

Comment: @jim I agree that the adjective may also apply to personal quality as well as to the nature of a question. It may also be used to describe comments, opinions, etc. I thank the questioner for their kind remarks.

Comment: Personally, I have a very strong preference for ***incisive*** in OP's context, and seeing the current vote tallies I assumed most others felt likewise. So I was somewhat surprised to see from [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asked+incisive+questions%2Casked+perceptive+questions&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) that the two alternatives have had almost exactly equal prevalence over the past century. Whatever - ***incisive*** alludes to the discomfort of the person required to answer, and ***perceptive*** alludes to the questioner's smarts.

Comment: Guessing at downvote reasons and I can see the point: how can a question be "good at noticing or understanding things"? Perception applies to the asker, not the question. Insightful seems to have the same problem except its definition includes one extra thing -- "having _or showing_ a deep understanding". An insightful question can show the asker's understanding. Of course, most dictionary definitions can't carry all of the nuance, but I thing here they get it right. A response to a good Q would be "that's very perceptive of you" vs. "that's a very insightful question".

Comment: @OwenReynolds A reasonable proposition. I take a more relaxed view that a perceptive question is one of a perceptive nature. Similarly we are used to hearing folk talk about stupid, leading or revealing questions. The qualifier to the question is not really attributable to the question in the same way as when we talk about a long or short question but is attributable to anyone who asks it. We are discussing a fine point.

Comment: EL&U is all about fine points. For example, the OP specifically wants "knowledge of the area" as opposed to being smart in general. That's pretty fine. And the definition of perceptive seems more the latter. I'm finally understanding jim's upvoted comment regarding that.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the most natural would be:
**Pertinent**

OED:

> **3. In later use esp. of comments, writing, etc.: referring or relating to; relevant; to the point; apposite.**
>
> 1875   B. Jowett in tr. Plato Dialogues (ed. 2) V. 131   *He..prefers a few good judges who make pertinent remarks on the case.*
>
> 1937   C. Odets Golden Boy i. ii. 33   *Ask yourself a pertinent remark: could a boy make a living playing this instrument in our competitive civilization to-day?*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I'm a (retired) programmer who was a tech writer. I'll pay more attention to the format here in future answers.

Answer (score 7):

Perspicacious

> having a ready insight into and understanding of things.

Comment: You need to attribute your source.

Answer (score 5):

You said...

> I really want to capture the perhaps-subtle meaning that the question demonstrates that the speaker themselves is well-read about the topic, rather than that the speaker/question is smart.

That implies that the question reflects, not the ability of the querent to perceive an interesting fact (astute, perceptive, observant, etc.), but is instead an expert on the subject, suggesting the questions reflect a very deep understanding of, or involvement with, the subject.

My first thought turned to *scholarly...*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scholarly)
>
> (1) containing a serious, detailed study of a subject.
> (2) A scholarly person studies a lot and knows a lot about what they study.

Then I turned to something like *pedagogical...*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pedagogical)
>
> relating to the methods and theory of teaching.

But I think that's too specific.

**I'm going to suggest *erudite...***

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/erudite)
>
> having or containing a lot of knowledge that is known by very few people.
>
> Also [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erudite)
>
> having or showing knowledge that is gained by studying.

Comment: An erudite question might demonstrate that the questioner is *generally* knowledgeable, but doesn't indicate knowledge about the topic. In a talk about AI, a classicist might ask an erudite question by making reference to the classical literature about hubris and linking it to modern themes, but it wouldn't demonstrate their knowledge about AI.

Comment: @dbmag9 Isn't your comment in conflict with the definition from Merriam-Webster? You appear to be upholding either a colloquial use above definitive use or the erudite question linking classical literature about hubris and modern themes reveals the speaker is well studied in both classical literature and modern themes - begging the question, "why are they giving a talk about AI in the first place?"

Comment: An erudite classicist might attend a talk about AI, and ask an erudite question ("showing knowledge that is gained by studying"), without themselves knowing much about AI. I'm writing from my own knowledge of the language but there's no contradiction with the definitions given here.

Comment: @dbmag9 Then we're in violent agreement. The setting of such a question isn't relevant. That it describes the educated nature of the querent is. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They are **penetrating** questions.

> **Penetrating** *adjective*
>
> 3 - showing that you have understood something quickly and completely
>
> - a penetrating comment/criticism/question

[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/penetrating#:%7E:text=%E2%80%8Bshowing%20that%20you%20have,a%20penetrating%20comment%2Fcriticism%2Fquestion)

Comment: I favour James' answer, even though it is rather brief. 
 First you have to think about what type of answer you get when you ask a question like that described.  The answer is likely to be that a good or complete answer to the question might yield an unexpected, interesting answer:  one that might make the asker or the person asked think or understand the topic differently.  The question has probably not been asked before and has some originality.

Several of the other answers already asked are good.  'Penetrating' is my personal preference.  But there are several good ones.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that you've already found the two best options: intelligent and knowledgeable.

Both are perfect for your use case. They are not as generalized as you think. Perhaps this is just an idiomatic interpretation, but **intelligent question** and **knowledgeable question** both imply a deeper understanding of the subject.

An intelligent question does not mean the person asking the question is smart in a general sense. The question is intelligent. People do not typically ask an intelligent question unless they demonstrate a deeper understanding of the topic. Sure, someone can accidentally ask an intelligent question without understanding the topic, but that is a minority of situations.

The same logic applies to "knowledgeable question". The word "knowledgeable" describes the question, not the person asking the question. A person could be regarded as not very smart in a general sense, but they can still ask a knowledgeable question if they have sufficient knowledge about the subject. Being "not smart" doesn't mean you know very little about everything. You can be someone who is "not smart" yet still have depth of knowledge on certain topics.

Lots of people have provided good alternatives, but they are not as good as the ones you already considered. Go with "intelligent" or "knowledgeable". Anecdotally, I think I hear "intelligent question" more often than "knowledgeable question" (speaking as someone from the mid-western portion of the USA).

Answer (score 0):

*Collins* gives **searching** with the below meaning and example.

> A "*searching question*" or look is intended to discover the truth about something.

*They asked her some searching questions on moral philosophy and logic.*

From the above, it could be said that a "*searching question"* demonstrates thought on part of the asker and isn't fatuous or rhetorical. By extension, one might argue that such a question would in all likelihood have broad implications.

Comment: _Searching_ does not pre-suppose prior deep knowledge.

Comment: @Conrado Maybe you're right, but I don't think one could really ask _searching/trenchant_ questions without having a certain hang of the subject at hand.

Answer (score 0):

**Telling** carries the required meaning, and I'd say the default meaning (*having a marked effect: 'a telling blow'*) can be disallowed by context:

> *telling*: ... (2) Revealing information ...
>
> - *a telling smile*

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/telling)]

He was obviously well-informed: he asked several telling questions.

Answer (score 0):

Astute.

> adjective having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations
> or people and turn this to one's advantage: an astute businessman.
>
> Origin. early 17th century: from obsolete French astut or Latin
> astutus, from astus ‘craft’.

-- OED